# VS12 Buiding Boost Library fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, boost-asio

I've been trying to build boost:asio for Visual Studio 2012.
I already did bjam and it gave me the include and lib addresses, which I pasted in VS settings.
Now compiler can't find 'libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_58.lib', but in stage lib I got the 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib', that is probably a newer version.

How can I solved this?
I searched it for days and couldn't get through this.

Comment: Building Boost is a Greek tragedy, just use the available [prebuilt binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using VisualStudio 2012 (is requesting vc110 version libraries) but you actually have build boost for Visual Studio 2013 (vc120).

You need to specify the right toolset to boost build (--toolset=msvc-11.0) and not let him pick the default.

Comment: Without the `--`, because `toolset` is a *feature* name, not an *option* name (the whole construct specifies a property). [A link to the docs](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html) might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks Marom, that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older-than-last version of boost?

Make sure that your version does not predate the support for VS2012. The mechanism for detecting the version is different in bjam and in the autolink headers, so that with recent versions of Visual Studio you can end up trying to link to the latest version known of boost "vc110", even though bjam detected it correctly.